# Finding the AS Number for IPs (~1M) in a file concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, network-programming, multiprocessing

Issue 1: So I have a file containing some 1M IP Addresses. I have to find the AS Number for each of those (IPWhois or whois). I am reading that file which in turn (.readlines()) stores it in a list. If I am reading the IP Addr one by one, it's going to take hours. So what I did was break the list into a hundred sublists (of 10k line each) and am running 99-100 processes. I am unable to figure out why this is still taking soooo much time. Any help would be appreciated. 
[In the lower part of the code, I am visiting the APnic site and checking what % of the internet is occupied by the ASnumber but this is unrelated to the problem.]

```
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint
import re
import shlex
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
# import requests
import os
from ipwhois import IPWhois
from multiprocessing import Process


def form_set(IP_List, asSet, countset):
    #    print("Yay!\n")
    for ip in IP_List:
        try:
            obj = IPWhois(ip.rstrip()).lookup_rdap(
                asn_methods=['dns', 'whois', 'http'])
            asn = obj['asn']
            # print(asn+'\n')
            if (asn[0].isdigit()) == True:
                asnNo = 'AS'+asn
                asSet.add(asnNo)
                #print(str(len(asSet))+'\n')
            else:
                #print(ip)
                countset.add(ip) // IPs for which there is no ASNo.
        except:
            countset.add(ip)
            continue


def main():
    count = 1
    asSet = set()
    file = open('ipList', 'r')
    IPs = file.readlines()
    processes = []
    ip_chunks = [IPs[x:x+10000] for x in range(0, len(IPs), 10000)]
    print(len(ip_chunks))

    countset = set()
    for ipchunk in ip_chunks:
        #        print('Calling for len(ipchunks) = ' + str(len(ipchunk)))
        p = Process(target=form_set, args=(ipchunk, asSet, countset, ))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print(asSet)
    url = 'https://stats.labs.apnic.net/aspop/'
    with requests.Session() as session:
        response = session.get(url)
        pattern = re.compile(
            r"table = new google\.visualization\.arrayToDataTable\((.*?)\);", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
        data = pattern.search(response.content).group(1)

        data = literal_eval(data)
        colperc = -1
        colasn = -1
        for header in data[0]:
            colperc = colperc + 1
            if header == "% of Internet":
                break

        for header in data[0]:
            colasn = colasn + 1
            if header == "ASN":
                break

        dictData = dict()
        for line in data:
            dictData[line[colasn]] = line[colperc]

        totalpercent = 0.0
        for asNo in asSet:
            if asNo in dictData.keys():
                totalpercent = totalpercent + dictData.get(asNo)

        print(totalpercent)
        print(count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[Issue 2: I have another issue with this ipwhois lookup but this is the primary one. Another issue is this - The ASNumber for a lot of IPs exist but IPWhois is giving errors like -
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
ipwhois.exceptions.HTTPLookupError: HTTP lookup failed for ....//rdap.afrinic.net/rdap/ip/~someip~ with error code 404.
But when I run whois -h whois.cymru.com **someip** it returns the AS Number.]

Comment: By a lot of time I mean, hours and hours and hours. A Day, maybe.

Comment: What kind of file format do you have your original list in?

Comment: @LTheriault  It's a text file.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like the reason everything may be going so slow, aside from the raw line count, is the fact that `readlines()` returns a list containing every single line in the file, meaning you're now working with those 1M addresses in memory. One way of iterating through the records is using a context manager instead, which won't store all of the lines in memory at the same time:

```
with open('ipList.txt', 'r') as file: 
    for line in file:
        ...
```

There is still a problem here because you eventually will have a ~1M record list to be working with. Especially if you research vectorization, you can find small tweaks and fixes that may be able to add additional speed for the actual application of the function itself.